# Most Recent Price for an Item

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have an issue where i cant find out how to get the latest price for an item.

My table consists of lots of fields but i only really need three

ITEM
UNITPRICE
AUDTDATE

What i want to see is

```
| ITEMNO | QTYONHAND |
|--------|-----------|
|      1 |         12|
|      2 |         13|
|      3 |          4|
```

Throught the course of time as im sure evberyone knows what you invoice the price at is different so what i want to see is only the most recent invoice price for every item.

I have tired

```
SELECT ITEM,UNITPRICE,max(AUDTDATE) from OEINVD
WHERE ITEM is NOT NULL
GROUP BY ITEM,UNITPRICE
ORDER BY ITEM
```

But it gives multiple for each sku :(

Ideally i want to see one sku and one price (latest price we invoiced at)

Please let me know if you can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `TIES` along with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ITEM, UNITPRICE, AUDTDATE
FROM OEI
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEM ORDER BY AUDITDATE DESC);
```

Comment: LEGEND !! you are the best !! worked perfectly !!
Thanks so much !!